# Running a Service with sudo administrator privileges

Tags: shell, applescript, sudo, symlink, automator

I have the following shell script that I normally run successfully as a system service (created in automator:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in "$@"
    do  ln -s "$f" "${f}.deleteThisExtensionAfterMoving"
    echo "${f}.deleteThisExtensionAfterMoving"
done
```

However, when trying to use this to make symlinks in folders that I'm not the owner of, it fails.

I tried saving it as a script, then using applescript in automator as I've seen described elsewhere here:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    do shell script ("sudo ~/Documents/z_misc/makesymlink '" & POSIX path of input & "'") with administrator privileges

end run
```

However, upon running the service, I see a "command not found" error.

When I tried saving the script as a .sh file and using that instead, it still didn't work. When I try running from terminal without the preceding "sudo" command, I get a "permission denied" error.

Comment: I am not very experienced with shell, but you don't have a command, instead you have a file after your sudo. Also, sudo isn't needed when using administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try running from terminal without the preceding "sudo" command, I get a "permission denied" error.

The "permission denied" error when attempting to execute a *shell script* (or *binary executable*) is typically caused because the *file* is not set as *executable*. Use the following *command* in **Terminal**:

```
chmod +x file
```

Or:

```
 chmod +x /path/to/file
```

- Quoting if there are *spaces* or escaping *spaces* with a *backslash* (`\`), but not both.

However, the "permission denied" error can also be caused if there is a privileges issue with where the *shell script* or *binary executable* is located.

Keeping executables in you **Documents** *folder* or any of the *default folders*, except for **Public**, within your **Home** folder can be problematic to **Automator** *actions* and for use in **Terminal**.

I created a `bin` *folder* in my **Home** folder and place my  *shell scripts* and *binary executables* that I do not want elsewhere, e.g. `/use/local/bin`, and have added `"$HOME/bin"` to my `PATH`.

Here is what I'd use in the **Run AppleScript** *action* in my **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```appleascipt
on run {input, parameters}
    
    repeat with thisItem in input
        
        set thisItem to the quoted form of the POSIX path of thisItem
        
        do shell script ("$HOME/bin/makesymlink " & thisItem) with administrator privileges
        
    end repeat
    
end run
```

As coded, this allows for multiple **Finder** *items* to be passed to the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*.

That all said, without seeing the contest of the `makesymlink` *file* there is not anything else I can think off at the moment.

---

From the linked Technical Note below:

**Note:** Using `sudo`(8) with `with administrator privileges` **is generally unnecessary and creates security holes; simply remove the** `sudo`.

Have a look at [Technical Note TN2065 **do shell script in AppleScript**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html)

If you are going to use the `do shell script` *command*, then I suggest you read the entire Technical Note.

Comment: Can you think of some way (either via a password prompt, or otherwise) when running a system service that would allow it to make symlinks in system folders, such as /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins?